# Under what conditions is $ \max_{a \in A} (f(a) - g(a)) \geq \max_{a \in A} f(a) - \max_{a \in A} g(a) $ true?

Tags: functions, inequality

Consider:
$$
\max_{a \in A} (f(a) - g(a)) \geq \max_{a \in A} f(a) - \max_{a \in A} g(a).
$$

Intuitively, it seems obvious it should be true, but I was having a hard time coming up with a rigorous precise proof under which conditions it is true.

It seems that to make the RHS big, a should be chosen to make $g(a)$ as big as possible and $f(a)$ as small as possible (ideally). However, the right hand side is doing nearly the exact opposite!

So intuitively, I would find it hard to believe that the above inequality is not true considering that the right hand side is clearly not finding the biggest difference. I hope this is right, so I was in search for a proof of this.

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(a) = (f(a) - g(a)) + g(a) \le
 \max_{a\in A}  (f(a) - g(a)) + \max_{a\in A} g(a) 
\\\implies  \max_{a\in A}f(a) \le \max_{a\in A}  (f(a) - g(a)) + \max_{a\in A} g(a) 
$$

Comment: $max_{a \in A} \{f(a) - g(a) \} \geq max_{a \in A}\{f(a)\} - max_{a \in A}\{g(a)\}$ is true? I don't need any conditions for it to be true? I am having a hard time following your proof, sorry!

Comment: @Pinocchio Well the maximum should exist in the first place (or you use the supremum instead, for which almost the same proof works)

Comment: @Pinocchio Note that the inequality $f(a) = \le
 \max_{a\in A}  (f(a) - g(a)) + \max_{a\in A} g(a) $ holds for all $a$. Therefore you can conclude the next step.

Comment: @Pinocchio there is really nothing fancy here. just hte definition of $\max$.